# How to trim the file extensions from a filename

Tags: powershell

I have a foreach loop that gets a list of objects in Folder4 after trimming the full path where the objects reside.

Here is sample code:

```
$row.Path = $path.InnerText.Replace("/Folder1/Folder2/folder3/folder4/","")
```

Sample Output:

```
usp_StoredProcedurename.prc,

fn_FunctionName.udf

File.sql
```

The last thing I need to do is to remove any extension, ie .prc, .pdf, .udf, .sql, etc

Here is the coplete for each:

[image]

Comment: Adding code as an image isn't good practice - it's better to paste it into your question **as text** (and then format it as code). Doing this means that anyone answering your question can easily use your code in their answer without having to manually re-type it all.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for the *static* [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) method. To use it, you have to pass a *single* file or path to it:

```
[System.Io.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("usp_StoredProcedurename.prc")
```

Depending on the actual output of `$row.Path` you could *split* the path and *join* them back later if you want.

---

Alternative, you could use a *regex* to remove the file extensions for alle files within your string *at once*:

```
$row.Path -replace '\..*'
```

Be aware that regex will remove *everything* after a dot.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have attached my sample code above, want to know how would the GetfilenamewithoutExtension or the Replace work.

I am pretty knew to powershell, can you help please??